# Ruby file output from fork

Tags: ruby, process, io, filesystems

I have one simple script:

```
fork do
  STDOUT.reopen(File.open('/tmp/log', 'w+'))
  STDOUT.sync = true
  exec 'bundle exec ruby script.rb'
end
```

script.rb:

```
loop do
    sleep 1
    puts "MESSAGE"
end
```

When it work, all outputs is buffering(?) and writes to `/tmp/log` by big pices.
It works only if I modify script:

```
$stdout.puts "MESSAGE"
$stdout.flush
```

How can I do the same **without** modifying `script.rb` ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `exec`, you create a new process, and although this process inherits the file you set as standard out, it doesn't inherit the other settings, in particular the sync setting.

In order to get unbuffered output in the new process, you need to set it in that process. If you don't want to modify `script.rb` one workaround could be to create another file, named somethig like `sync.rb` containing just:

```ruby
STDOUT.sync = true
```

which you can then require when running your command:

```ruby
exec 'bundle exec ruby -r./sync script.rb'
```

The new Ruby process will now require `sync.rb`, which simply sets sync mode on `STDOUT` to true before executing your script.